# Finding the microphone settings on Android One 10

Tags: audio, microphone, android-10, headset, android-one

My headset microphone has stopped working recently, and I would like to have a look in the microphone settings to fix the issue. However, I cannot find any setting related to the microphone volume, noise filters, etc. (such as described [in point 1 here](https://milagromobilemarketing.com/blog/change-microphone-settings-android/)) in the settings app.

Where could I find the related settings? I cannot imagine that there are no microphone settings, but if this is the case, could there be an app that would give me more control?

I am using Android One 10 on a Nokia 6.2.

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks! From what I can see, however, the apps are made for testing, not for changing the global settings. For example, I may want to change the audio source from the headset to the built-in microphone, if I cannot fix the issue on time.

Comment: [This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jami.tool.hiddensetting) *may* help. Mic settings which you are looking for don't show up for me on Android 10, may have been dropped

Comment: @beeshyams This is an interesting app. However, searching vor "mic", "call" or "call" yielded no results.

Comment: Yes, like I said, nothing on my device but was wondering if it would help. Conclusion - that setting has been dropped